# How to produce two empty lines in a macro?

Tags: macros

I want to create a qrcode matching a predefined template that contains two empty lines. I'm using the qrcode package, and everything is fine, if I just put

```
\qrcode{a


b}
```

in my document. The code is generated, and scans with the two empty lines.

However, I absolutely cannot figure out, how to wrap this call in a \newcommand. When I try

```
\newcommand{\mycode}[2]{%
\qrcode{#1


#2}}

\mycode{a}{b}
```

I receive the treaded

> ! Paragraph ended before \qrcode@in was
>   complete.

error. I've read all about how TeX reads the input (the famous "Chapter 8" and more), and when empty lines become \par, etc., but I've failed to find the loophole around this problem. I've tried \char13\char13, which failes with

> Missing \endcsname inserted.

So how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code.

Comment: `\newcommand{\mycode}[2]{%
\qrcode{#1}\\[+2\baselineskip]\qrcode{#2}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a macro, which can call `\qrcode` in its body and grabs arguments, you should also set `\qr@verbatimcatcodes` before reading the argument, this way your macro can behave in the same way `\qrcode` behaves. Additionally, you should use `\?` to include the newlines, like @egreg already suggested:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mycode
  {%
    \begingroup
    \qr@verbatimcatcodes
    \mycode@
  }
\newcommand\mycode@[2]
  {%
    \qrcode{#1\?\?#2}%
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mycode{a}{b}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using the `qrcode` package, you can find the relevant part of the manual:

[image]

(page 5).

Use `\?` instead of an empty line.